# Do not want to close modal after submit data in modal PHP

Tags: javascript, php, form-submit, simplemodal

I want to stay same modal after submitting this form

`generateBarcode.php`:

```
<form action="savegenarateBarcode.php?id=<?php echo $d1; ?>" method="post">
```

`savegenerateBarcode.php`:

```
<?php
try {
    session_start();
    include('../connect.php');

    $d1 = $_GET['id'];
    $b = $_POST['serialnumber'];
    $sqlm = "select *from product_item where serialnumber='".$b."'";

    $query = $db->prepare($sqlm);
    $user_array = $query ->execute();
}
```

How can I stay same `generateBarcode.php(modal)` after submitting this form?

Comment: stay same ?? you mean redirect into the form after submit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `ajax` because the form `submit` method reload the page.

```
var id = '<?php echo $d1; ?>';
$("#submit").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "savegenarateBarcode.php",
            data:`id=${id}`
            success:function(data){
             alert(data);
            }
        });
    return false;
    });
```